# iOS: 3 UILabels under each other constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have 3 `UILabes`under each other. Top constraint of the first one is `20` to `superview`, second one is `20` to `first label`. 3rd is `20` to the `second` one. But sometimes first and second label's texts are empty. And I just want to make my 3rd label become `20` to `superview`, but when my constraints are set it becomes `20+20+20 to superview.`

Is it possible to fix this only using storyboard or I have to use some code.

I am sorry for my poor english, help me out.

Comment: What are the other constraints..???
May be you are not setting other constraints correctly.

Comment: yes you can fix this by storyboard plz wait i give the answer.

Comment: @balkaransingh I am waiting for you

Comment: @ArtemZ. i try but you need to take to at least two IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that programmatically, Take the Outlet of the `Height` and `Top Space` constraints of all Labels.

Check for Labels text, if blank then set `Height` and `Top Space` constraints `Constant` to `0`.

*Like,*

If First label text is blank then Set 1st label `Height constraint` Constant to `0` and `Top Space` constraint `Constant` to `0`. Same way you can check for other labels.

Comment: I don't want to make this programmatically, just asked about the storyboard

Comment: @ArtemZ. It's not possible to do in storyboard. You have to add code for this.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your requirement i have created one demo for it with 3 labels. But i have added those 3 labels in Stack View with vertical orientation. And then i have added one button in UIView outside of Stack View, then on button click i have hidden 2nd label. Doing this i got the result which you need.

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    lbl2.hidden = true
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Stack views will work only above iOS version 9.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

You can add each label inside a UIView. Make the top Label constraint to be 20 to superview (in this case will be 20 to top of the container UIView).
Then make UIView 1 to have top 0 to superview. UIView 2 to have top 0 to UIView 1 and UIView 3 to be 0 to UIView 2.

Then you can hide each UIView, when you don't have any text in it's corresponding UILabel so they will display nicely.